# Redux state is filled but I get error state is null

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, state, store

I'm currently working on a project which involves logged in users. In my redux state I have a user which is an object that isn't null. But when I try to get a role from this user object I suddenly get an error "state is null"

```
this.props.userState.user
```

returns an user object which has a role attribute.

```
this.props.userState.user.role
```

throws an error "TypeError: this.props.userState.user is null"

edit: the following is all the code in the entire file.

```
class ResultsMain extends Component {

componentDidMount() {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
        if (user)
            getUser(user.email).then(foundUser => {
                console.log('User found:', foundUser);
                this.props.doSetUser(foundUser);
            }).catch((err) => {
                console.log(err)
                this.props.history.push('/');
            });
    });
}

render() {
    console.log("THE PROPS", this.props.userState.user)
    if (this.props.userState.role === "teacher") return <TeacherSearchPage/>
    else return <Results />
    //else return <div> </div>
}
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        userState: state.userState,
    }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        doSetUser: user => dispatch(userActions.setUser(user)),
    }
}

export const resultsMainPage = ReactRedux.connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ResultsMain);
```

The reducer:

```
const initialState = {
    user: null,
    finished: false,
}

function copyAndUpdateObj(copiedObject, update) {
    return Object.assign({}, copiedObject, update);
}

export default function userReducer(state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case INSERT_USER:
            return {...state, user: action.userInformation};
        case SET_USER: {
            let changes = {
                user: action.user
            }
            return copyAndUpdateObj(state, changes);
        }
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before anyone can help you

Comment: initial state of user is null ?

Comment: Can you share some code base?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reducer must be something of the sort:

```
function reducer(state = initialState, action) {...}
```

Whatever is the value of `this.props.userState` comes from your definition of `initialState` at the very beginning. Please make sure to define `initialState` object in your application.

Double check if you have you defined `userState.user` in your initial state.

Comment: The reducer is declared using an Initialstate, I'll edit my post and include this reducer. The way the user object is filled is by using GitHub authentication through Firebase via cloud-functions, so the reducer only inserts this object into the state.

Comment: the state is called `user` in your reducer and you are trying to access it as `userState` in your component.